# How do I get a list of objects from a form in razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I need to receive a list of items from the user.  Specifically I have recipes(a restaurant menu item) that has a list of ingredients.  I need a page where the user can put in any number of ingredients for each recipe.  I need to return a list of ingredients for each recipe to the back end.

I have searched for hours but I can't find a solution that works for me.  I think that I need to do something with Html.BeginCollectionItem, but I don't really understand how it works and I can't even get it to install.  Also I have been trying to work with partials, but to no avail.

## newRecipes.cshtml

```
@model AddRecipesView

@foreach(Recipe recipe in Model.Recipes){
    Display each recipe here as well as a dropdown(or list of
    dropdowns) for the user to add as many ingredients to the recipe
    as they like"
}
```

## AddRecipesView.cs

```
public class AddRecipesView{
    public Merchant Merchant{get;set;}

    public List<Recipe> Recipes{get;set;}
}
```

## Merchant.cs

```
public class Merchant{
    public string id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string LastCheckedTime{get;set;}

    public List<Pantry> PantryItems{get;set;}

    public List<Recipe> Recipes{get;set;}
}
```

## Recipe.cs

```
public class Recipe{
    public string id{get;set;}
    public string name{get;set;}

    public string MerchantId{get;set;}
    public Merchant Merchant{get;set;}

    public List<RecipeComponent> RecipeComponents{get;set;}
}
```

## Controller

```
[HttpGet("recipes/new")]
public IActionResult NewRecipes(){
    AddRecipesView viewModel = CreateAddRecipesView();          

    return View("newRecipes", viewModel);
}

public AddRecipesView CreateAddRecipesView(){
        AddRecipesView viewModel = new AddRecipesView();

        viewModel.Merchant = context.Merchants
            .Include(m => m.PantryItems)
            .ThenInclude(pi => pi.Ingredient)
            .FirstOrDefault(m => m.id == merchantId);

        string json = new WebClient().DownloadString($"https://apisandbox.dev.clover.com/v3/merchants/{merchantId}/items?access_token={token}");
        Items items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Items>(json);
        foreach(ItemElement item in items.elements){
            Recipe recipe = context.Recipes.FirstOrDefault(r => r.id == item.id);
            viewModel.Recipes.Append(recipe);
        }

        return viewModel;
    }
```

I need to get from the user a list of ingredients for each recipe.  I am simply unsure of how to do this with cshtml.

Comment: Are you using Razor Pages or MVC? If you're using Razor Pages, then the logic goes in your Page Model. If you're using MVC then the logic goes in a Controller Action.

Comment: I am using MVC for this.  How would I go about adding the logic in the controller?  Sorry, I am new to this, I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: can you add your controller for the view?

Comment: @GabLlorico Added the controller.

Comment: @LeeMorgan does your viewModel has values?

Comment: @LeeMorgan also, does your `foreach` contain codes? like `recipe.Name`?